# VirtualHost apache 2.2

Tags: linux, apache, linux-mint

some months ago I had apache 2.4 and I could create virtualhost, but now I had to change my apache version  to 2.2 and my virtualhost is not working, I also have linux mint 17
my virtualhost file is the next: zendvirtual.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin roberth@zend
 ServerName zend
 ServerAlias zend
 DocumentRoot /var/www/frameworks/zend/public
 <Directory /var/www/frameworks/zend/public>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Someone knows if I have to add something more, a new line, another configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```
Require all granted
```

is not supported under Apache 2.2. The equivalent is:

```
Allow from all
```